# Push Notification on google docs doc update

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, sdk, push-notification

I have no experience with push notifications, but I have been working with iOS for a while. How do I send a push notification to a user (i.e. a little red '1' in the app icon like mail or messages) when a google docs document has been updated? Is there even a way?

Comment: I don't think is possible to watch for changes on a Google Docs document (It will be amazing if is possible). But anyway, setting a Notification Server is a very discussed subject, and there's a lot of info out there.

Comment: Not sure if Google has an API which can be invoked to get the last updated datetime for a document. If there is an API like that then you can call this API and store the last updated date for the document on your server. You can call this google API every 5minutes or more based on your requirements, if the date you have on your server and last updated date you get from Google API mismatches then send notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this on spreadsheets, but it will require some setup for each person who uses your app.

1. Follow [these instructions](http://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=91588) to get notifications from Google when
   a spreadsheet is modified.
2. Create a server that will save your e-mail username and password and notice when Google e-mails you a notification of a new
   modification.
3. Set up your server to interact with Apple's Push Notification Service (here's some info)

   - [Apple: Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1)
   - [Apple: Troubleshooting Push Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html)
   - [Mark Aufflick: ￼Introduction to Apple Push Notification Service](http://mark.aufflick.com/files/view/talks/apns.pdf)

It's complicated, but it could make a killer app.  There's also a [GMail API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/) you could use to get access to the user's inbox feed.

Comment: (Note that Google only supports notifications on spreadsheets - it won't work on presentations or text documents.)

Comment: @ConorTaylor - can you provide some more details?